# Location Authorization not prompting

Tags: ios, swift, location, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I am new to iOS and swift. I am using MapKit, and I am trying to update the location of the user. I have determined that it is not running the `didUpdateLocations` method. I am trying to use the `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` and `requestAlwaysAuthorization` methods, but still nothing.

Here is the error:

```
Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.
```

Here is the code:

```
if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
        println("CLLocationManager")
        manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        updateCoordinates()

        let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    }
```

I have also tried putting the `requests` after the `delegate`, and then after the `desiredAccuracy` as well.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must added to yourApp-info.plist this key : NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription (Better both).  You add this key and the text is the message to request use to  the user.

Comment: Might add that the documentation for both `requestAlwaysAuthorization` and `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` mentions this requirement.  It seems unlikely that you'd actually need both, although I suppose there are a few situations that might scale back functionality if tracking is only allowed when in use.

Comment: You only need one, depends on the service your app need. If your app don´t need any location service in background you should use: requestWhenInUseAuthorization (call this methods, and implement the key in info.plist). If you need service in background (like regions alert), you need the request for Always. This last in more privacy invasive and you must explein to the user why need your App this services.